# best practices for table partitioning - mysql 5.5

Tags: mysql, innodb, partitioning

I have a mysql 5.5 server with a big (~150M records) innodb table that I want to partition.

How can I determine the optimal number of partitions for the table?

The table is a "many-to-many" connection table that consists of only two int columns (aId, bId),

aId receives values roughly on the range of 1..1,000,000
bId receives values roughly on the range of 1..10,000,000

Most queries lookup aId first.

the table has two indexes:
primary(aId, bId)
index(bId)

And, again, the question is How can I determine the optimal number of partitions for the table?

Thanks

Comment: I would recommend you read MySQL's article on [Improving Database Performance with Partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/partitioning.html).

Comment: It's a great article, thanks.
But it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @strum: You haven't specified *why* you want to partition the table. What gains are you hoping for?

Comment: hi, sorry for the delay... the goal was speeding up queries on that table.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to structure your data logically, then optimal number of partitions is the same as number of cores on the server. This will aid multiple concurrent queries. Individual queries will run the same time due to using primary index.

I would suggest changing your second index to `index (bld,ald)`, so bld to ald queries can use only index to get ald value, without going to the database for it.